# Simple Key Listener does not work NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt, keylistener

i am using NetBeans to build my application.

All my mouse listeners are works great, but key listener does not listening at all.

```
private void viewport1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    System.out.println(evt.VK_SPACE);    
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == evt.VK_SPACE) {
            System.out.println("Bingo");
 }
```

No output from there, and where i use evt.VK_SPACE Netbeans alerts me about accessing static field.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: "accessing a static field" means ... you're accessing a static field from an instance of the class. Should be `KeyEvent.VK_SPACE` - the field is a static member.

Comment: But i can't edit first line, it is generated by netbeans

Comment: Use [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should be;

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
```

If you cant edit code because its generated by netbeans, you can do that in form editor. (customize code..)